# How to time how long it takes for Akka HTTP to complete HTTP request

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have built a flow which takes a case class (`Event`) and sends it to a HTTP endpoint and returns it back. It's implemented like so:

```
Flow[Event]
    .mapAsync(16)(eventToHttpRequest)
    .via(connection)
    .map(handleResponse)
```

For reference, here is the `handleResponse` method:

```
def handleResponse(endpoint: String)(responseTuple: (Try[HttpResponse], Event))(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem, mat: ActorMaterializer) = {
    responseTuple match {
      case (Success(response), event) =>
        response.status.intValue() match {
          case code if code >= 500 =>
            val message = s"Server side error sending event with id ${event.id} to ingestion gateway, status : ${response.status}"
            LOG.error(message)
            response.discardEntityBytes()
            throw new UnexpectedException(message)
          case code if (code >= 400) && (code < 500) =>           
            val message = s"Bad request sending  event with id ${event.id} to ingestion gateway, status : ${response.status}"
            LOG.error(message)
            throw new UnexpectedException(message)
          case _ =>
            LOG.debug(s"Sent event with id ${event.id}, status : ${response.status}")
            response.discardEntityBytes()
            event
        }
      case (Failure(ex), justDataEvent) =>
        LOG.error(s"Could not connect to $endpoint")
        throw ex
    }
  }
```

I would like to monitor how long the HTTP request takes. "How long a request takes" could be thought of as:

1. How long until we get back the initial headers and status code
2. How long until we get the entire body in memory

In this case they will be very similar, as the response is small, but it would be good to know how to compute both.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Where is the "monitored" time supposed to go?

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil lets get the value first then i can think about where to put it, if need be can store it in the event case class but thats not too important

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I thought i was clear, how do i time how long a http request takes using akka streams?

Comment: Your answer to my question will affect my answer to yours...

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil Lets say i dont need to store it at all beyond a local val as i have a class with will emit it to a monitoring service as a side effect

Comment: e.g val time = getTimeTake(); monitoring.record(time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the request response cycle this can be implemented with an intermediate flow that adds a start time to the http request and event:

```
type EventAndTime = Tuple2[Event, Long]

val addQueryTime : Tuple2[HttpRequest, Event] => Tuple2[HttpRequest, EventAndTime] = 
  (tup) => (tup._1, (tup._2, java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()))

val addQueryTimeFlow : Flow[(HttpRequest, Event), (HttpRequest, EventAndTime),_] = 
  Flow[(HttpRequest, Event)] map addQueryTime
```

Now `handleRequest` will receive the `Event` and the system time after going through the `conn`:

```
Flow[Event]
  .mapAsync(16)(eventToHttpRequest)
  .via(addQueryTimeFlow)
  .via(connection)
  .map(handleResponse)
```

`handleRequest` can just ask for the system time again and do a diff.

You can do a similar trick with `response.entity` to time how long that takes:

```
val timeout : FiniteDuration = ???

case class EntityAndTime(strict : Strict, startTime : Long, endTime : Long)

val entity = response.entity

val entityAndTime : Future[EntityAndTime] = 
  Future(System.currentTimeMillis())
  .flatMap { startTime => 
    entity
      .toStrict(timeout)
      .map { strict =>
        EntityAndTime(strict, startTime, System.currentTimeMillis())
      }
  }
```